# react-native-router-flux nested tabs

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux and I'm trying to add a tabbar withing a scene inside a tab, like a double tabbar sort of thing. It works on iOS but it doesn't on Android

```
<Router createReducer={reducerCreate}>
  <Scene key="tabbar" tabs={true} style={styles.tabBar}>
    <Scene key="tab0" title="nested" icon={TabIcon}>
      <Scene key="tabbar2" tabs={true} style={styles.tabBar} icon={TabIcon}>
        <Scene key="subtab1" title="subtab1" component={Results} icon={TabIconResults} initial={true} />
        <Scene key="subtab2" title="subtab2" component={Results} icon={TabIconResults}/>
        <Scene key="subtab3" title="subtab3" component={Results} icon={TabIconResults}/>
      </Scene>
    </Scene>                           
    <Scene key="tab1" component={TabView} title="Réservations" icon={TabIcon} />
    <Scene key="tab2" component={TabView} title="Compte" icon={TabIcon}/>     
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: Hi @red-devil! No not really!, made that question 5 years ago! I've been lately using another package that works quite well, have a look, https://reactnavigation.org/